# Apache pig convert to YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ date format

Tags: date, datetime, hadoop, apache-pig

I want to convert the dat format in pig to the solr date format (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ). I am not sure how i do it. can someone help me with this.

Thanks,
Stacky

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datetime parsing in Apache Pig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288819/datetime-parsing-in-apache-pig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToDate(*time column to convert*, '*format present in the given column*') AS (*column name*:datetime)

e.g.

```
ToDate(time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS (time:datetime)
```